# Delete till first character on next line

Tags: vim, neovim

I have code that looks like this:

```
DataAssociator::Impl::Impl(const VoxelHasherSettings& settings_voxelhasher,
                           const CameraSettings& settings_camera)
{
    initialize(settings_camera);
}
```

When I position my cursor on the `c` of the first `const` and press either `+` or `<CR>` I move to the next `const`.

However pressing `d+` / `d<CR>` deletes too much and leaves this:

```
{
    initialize(settings_camera);
}
```

1. Why is that the case?
2. How do I achieve the effect of deleting till the first character on the next line?

I am using neovim.

Thanks in advance,
Richard

Comment: You have to escape `<` as `&lt;` or (better here) just format as code (which escapes implicitly) by enclosing in backticks. I've done that edit for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you check out [`:help +`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#%2B), this mentions *linewise*. So when you use `+` in normal mode, it moves (as documented) to the first non-blank, but after an operator (like `d` or `y`), all touched lines will be included by default.

You can change that default behavior on a case-by-case basis via [`:help o_v`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#o_v): So `dv+` instead of `d+`.

Alternatively, you can first go into visual mode; the selection will provide feedback on what text you'll be covering: `v+d`. A complication here is that depending on your `'selection'` setting, this may select one character too much (with the default `inclusive` selection).

Comment: Ha! You inadvertently answered another question of mine. I am trying to get used to not using visual mode. Apart from dv+ which works perfectly your link taught me that C-v allows me to do block-edits without block-visual mode. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it's a bad habit (mostly from other editors, where you have no other choice) to use visual mode by default. If there's a direct motion, use that. On the other hand, hesitating or having to undo to get the motion right also isn't efficient. Visual mode is great to iteratively obtain the correct area.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option for this specific case:
<kbd>D</kbd><kbd>J</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>